# WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 classpath issue: httpclient classes cannot be found

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

On WSO2ESB 4.6.0, I want to deploy a service that depends on `redmine-java-api` version 1.23. When I look at maven dependencies of the library, I see it requires `httpclient` 4.2. Although, I put `httpclient` jar in `$ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib` folder, I get  the exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager`.

Inside the jar, there is a package named `org.apache.http.impl.conn` and that package contains the class definition of `PoolingClientConnectionManager`.

I cannot figure out the problem. What could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the exact solution. But there is httpclient jar file that is shipped with WSO2ESB by default. I think, it is httpclient 4.1.X jar that does not contain the "PoolingClientConnectionManager" class. In OSGI run time, this jar file may set as the dependency for redmine-java-api (not your httplclient 4.2)  However you can get some idea...  by starting the WSO2ESB with OSGI console.

> sh wso2server.sh  -DosgiConsole

Using OSGI console, you check what are the jar files that "org.apache.http.impl.conn" package has been exposed to the OSGI run time of the WSO2ESB. And also it would list down the all the bundles which use the given package. Please use following command.

> packages org.apache.http.impl.conn

Answer (score 0):

Have you import the package in MANIFEST.INF file of the bundle ?